# CORS post doesn't work with rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cors, remote-access

I wan't to login in my app, through another domain. I have setup the headers on the server side like this:

application.rb:

```
    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method' => 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '1728000'
}
```

These doesn't seem to do anything.

In the application controller:

```
before_filter :expire_hsts

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :current_user, :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control 

headers.

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

# If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
# request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
# text/plain.

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == :options
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '*'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
```

This is the request I send with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/login",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,

                data: {
                    "email": "admin@example.com",
                    "password" : "foobar",
                    "remember_me": "0"
                }
                /*xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }*/
            }).done(function(result) {
                $('html').html(result);
            });
```

A GET request to this page would work and would show the page on the screen. Nevertheless I need to post, to login. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the [`Rack::CORS`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem.**

--

It creates middleware which sorts out all the headers for your app. I've never seen anyone manually implement the headers properly in their controllers or whatever, this app does it for you:

```
  #config/application.rb
  ....
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
    end
  end
```

Comment: I can explain more if you need. Installing and running this gem should be self-explanatory though.